# Creating chart depending on template Dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm using Dash. That's how I load graph in template:

```
{% load plotly_dash %}
<div class="{% plotly_class name="SimpleExample" %} card" style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
 {% plotly_app name="SimpleExample" ratio=0.65 %}
</div>
```

SimpleExample app:

```
app = DjangoDash('SimpleExample')
plot_div = {
    'data': [
        {'x': [1], 'y': [2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'som'},
    ]
}
app.layout = html.Div(dcc.Graph(figure=plot_div))
```

I want to create chart based on argument in template. So I would like to have something like this:

```
{% plotly_app argument name="SimpleExample" ratio=0.65 %}
```

and in SimpleExample e.g.

```
plot_div = {
    'data': [
        {'x': [argument], 'y': [2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'som'},
    ]
}
```